# FInding the webkit version used in Android browser?

Tags: android, webkit, version

Is there a way to tell which version of the webkit software is used in the Android browser on some specific handset?

What would be really great is if there is a URL you can browse to get that information.   But any other way would be good too.   If you know the webkit version, you know how much html5 suport to expect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Android 2.3.3, at least, the version of Webkit is reflected in the user agent string.

When I go to [WhatsMyUserAgent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) on my Android device with 2.3.3 (Cyanogenmod 7.0.3), I get:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC Vision Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML; like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

Comment: I get a similar report on my phone; what a mess.

Answer (score 6):

This site has a summary for you http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/

Comment: Links may break. So you'd better quote some of the info in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

When you type `javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)` in the location bar you'll see the WebKit version listed e.g.

> Emulator Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-us; GT-N8000
>   Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Safari/534.30

Answer (score 3):

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
String useragent=webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

The useragent is the reuslt like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-N900 Build/KOT49H)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0
>   Mobile Safari/537.36

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use

```
PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.webview", 0);
String version = pi.versionName;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Javascript library from several years ago that can do this.  Not sure how up-to-date it is:
http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/DetectingWebKit