# CSS and Java script on webview affected by the Android versions?

Tags: android, webview, version

I used some style sheet and JavaScript to do some stuff with Android webview. But Android works differently when the API level changes.

My project targets Android 2.1 update API level 7. 
I wrote a JavaScript function that searches and highlights a word from webview. It works fine in 2.2 version (API level 8) but not working in 2.1 version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the WebView is effected by the Android versions,the Android version effects the Webkit(Which have a WebCore and JavaScriptCore) version,so it will effects the CSS and js rendering.

Comment: can you provide some background for your answer?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412518/finding-the-webkit-version-used-in-android-browser